# Php form isset with multiple brackets

Tags: php, checkbox, isset

I have a check box with a name of:

```
<input type='checkbox' name ='schedule[".$row['id']."][1]' />
```

I want to check if the check box was checked with the PHP `isset(...)` And I tried it as

```
isset($_POST['schedule[".$row['id']."][1]]);
```

But this didn't work. Any ideas that how It can works?

Comment: Add complete input html. This is not a well formatted/planned question. However try to print  $_POST array after form submit on action page. You'll have to use index in same way it is getting printed.

Comment: I think you have to (specify) a name,  don't  make it dynamic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try it like:

```
isset($_POST['schedule'][$row['id']][1])
```

Simply treat it as multi-D array in this case and edit particular index of schedule key.

Answer (score 0):

After the submission of `form` the GLOBAL VARIABLES `$_POST` passes the data as `string` or `int` instead of original variables.

To check if `checkbox` was *checked* try this one:

```
$id = $row['id'];
if(isset($_POST['schedule'][$id][1])) {
     echo "hello world";
}
```